# CodeIgniter: How to remove message from URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a message that is passed on to the user on the page (say if they write in a wrong email address or password) but it's also shown in the url.

http://domain/login?message=You%20have%20been%20logged%20out%20of%20site.

this is an example. shows the user has logged out. another ?message could be "you have typed a wrong password" (with %20 for spaces of course)

how do i get rid of that? and just either have them re-direct to /login or something like /login/leave or login/wrong-info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're passing the message with `$_GET`. You better use the sessions `flashdata()` function that comes with CI. Here's the [link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html). Search for Flashdata.

Comment: thanks a lot for alerting me about flashdata. it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, flashdata should be the way to go there...

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

You should also note that CodeIgniter **does not support** the GET array by default.